# web api inserting duplicate rows

Tags: php, mysql

My Code:

```
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mis","root","");

$name = $_POST['name'];
$transaction_status = $_POST['transaction_status'];
$client_id = $_POST['client_id'];
$group_id = $_POST['group_id'];

$statement = $con->prepare("select transaction_id from transaction_process where client_id='$client_id' and group_id='$group_id'"); 
$statement->execute();

$data = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($data){
..update query
} else {
..insert query
}
```

> Above mentioned is my code sample.

This code executes when web api get called by clients and thousands of transactions collected per minute.
So the issue is that, many times i face duplicate records with same group_id and client_id, i tried many more amendments in above select query but still facing same problem.

I can provide more details if required, but want to get out of it. 
Please support.

Comment: additionally, all the column that are being used in searching are well indexed too.

Comment: just check it by counting the number of rows first, if exists then update else insert new, and why in the world are you still directly injecting values in your sql statement? the prepare method is useless

Comment: Before ineserting, add a flag to check if transaction record exists for given `group_id` and `client_id`. If yes, either update it or skip it. Of course, if you have defined unique key for `group_id` and `client_id`.

Comment: Dear @Ghost , i am using sql injection but here in sample, did not mentioned. please ignore that mistake. :)

Comment: If user send 2 http request then you have two row with same fields you can avoid it by checking if row is already available as described by @Ghost

Comment: Use [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: @Ghost can you elaborate what is the difference between counting rows and select query as i used above.

Answer (score 1):

Given the number of connections you have going to the api, you probably need to `write lock` your transactions. Please note that during the lock process, other sessions will not be able to read and write data (but this should be relatively quick).

```
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mis", "root", "");

$name = $_POST['name'];
$transaction_status = $_POST['transaction_status'];
$client_id = $_POST['client_id'];
$group_id = $_POST['group_id'];

try {
    $con->exec('LOCK TABLE transaction_process WRITE');

    $statement = $con->prepare("SELECT transaction_id 
                                      FROM transaction_process 
                                      WHERE client_id = :clientId and group_id = :groupId");
    $statement->bindParam(':clientId',$client_id);
    $statement->bindParam(':groupId',$group_id);
    $statement->execute();

    $data = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($data) {
        do_something();
    } else {
         do_something_else();
    }

    $con->exec('UNLOCK TABLES');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // catch any exceptions ..
}
```

For a bit more information on table locking check out this [table locking tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-table-locking/) or the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables.html)

Comment: Should I use locking and unlocking in entire queries or wherever I am inserting and updating?

Comment: I would say that you want to lock it when you're starting your checks for whether the row exists or not.